# jQuery animate div sliding up and not covering text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have some HTML which basically has a div with text in it. I created a second div with absolute positioning and I want it to slide up (originally hidden below the main div) to give the effect of the div filling with new background color.

I got the div to slideup, but it always covers the original text. How do I keep it from doing that.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SmAHU/206/

Code:
HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="blue">Hey</div>
    <div id="green"></div> </div> <input type="button" value="up" id="button" />
```

CSS

```
#container    {position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:50px; width:50px; }
#blue         {height:50px; width:50px; background:#009; position:relative; top:0; left:0; color:white;}
#green        {height:50px; width:50px; background:#090; position:absolute; top:50px; left:0;}
```

Jquery

```
$('#button').toggle(function() {
    $('#green').animate({
        top: 0
    }, 1000, function() {
        $('#button').val('down');
    });
}, function() {
    $('#green').animate({
        top: '50'
    }, 1000, function() {
        $('#button').val('up');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply wrap a `span` element around the `#blue` element's text.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="blue">
        <span>Text</span>
    </div>
    <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

Then position the `span` element and increase the `z-index`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/epo71omj/)

```
#blue > span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```